# Error message "Unable to debug Apache Cordova apps on Windows Phone 8 targets"

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to debug a Apache Cordova project in Visual Studio for Windows Phone 8.1. The app has a originally been built on phonegap build for multiple platforms, but since I need to debug it I need to recreate it in visual studio.

When I attempt to debug the app (F5 in VS) the following warning message appears
"Unable to debug Apache Cordova apps on Windows Phone 8 targets. See documentation for alternatives: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=511664&clcid=0x409  DFO_wp81

I'm running visual studio 2015 preview with Tools for Cordova version 0.3.110414.2. I'm using a physical devices with Windows 8.1 update 1 and the issue also shows up in the 8.1 emulators.

The plaform for the project is set to Windows Phone (Universal) and the config.xml of the project refers to windows phone 8.1 as target:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps" id="io.cordova.DFOwp81" version="1.0.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
  <name>DFO_wp81</name>
  <description>A blank project that uses Apache Cordova to help you build an app that targets multiple mobile platforms: Android, iOS, Windows, and Windows Phone.</description>
  <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">Apache Cordova Team </author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <preference name="windows-target-version" value="8.1" />
  <preference name="windows-phone-target-version" value="8.1" />
  <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" version="0.2.11" />
  <vs:platformSpecificValues />
</widget>
```

Am I missing some config of the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll recommend you uninstall the VS 2015 preview (and all dependent compenents including Cordova tools) and install the [latest VS 2015 CTP](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/visual-studio-2015-ctp-vs) build.

Comment: Thanks, installed the latest VS 2015 CTP and was able to debug with Winphone 8.1